# How to pass parameters to Geoserver Heatmap SLD

Tags: geoserver, openlayers, heat-map

I am trying to generate heatmap using [Geoserver Transformation SLD](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/styling/sld-extensions/rendering-transform.html#heatmap-generation). as mentioned on the page, It requires few parameters:

1. data
2. weightAttr
3. radiusPixels
4. pixelsPerCell
5. outputBBOX
6. outputWidth and
7. outputHeight

I am able to use it by specifying these parameters directly in SLD as default parameters. But I am not able to pass it as OpenLayers request. There is my code:

```
    var layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Heat Map",
      "http://port/geoserver/wms", 
      {
        layers: 'work:cbsa_pop', 
        format: "image/png",
        transparent: "true",
        styles:'heatmap',
        maxExtent: new OpenLayers.Bounds(-124.269,32.545,-114.354,41.956),
        projection: new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),
        data:'data_attr',
        weightAttr:'w_attr',
        radiusPixels:100,
        pixelsPerCell:100,
        BBOX:new OpenLayers.Bounds(-124.269,32.545,-114.354,41.956),
        outputWidth:1000,
        outputHeight:1000
    });
```

This way it is not accepting any of the parameter. Any guidance will be helpful.

Comment: please show the full error

Comment: @iant : It is not giving any error but I am also not getting image which in other case (SLD with default specification), I am getting proper Heatmap.

Answer (score 2):

Look at the "env" filter function, you can pass parameters to it via the env=k1:v1;k2:v2 request parameter.

Comment: I tried that way but i am getting error .. `Unexpected token = `